# “TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'”

Tags: python

El programa que les presento es de un inventario de quesos, pero al momento de ejecutar la venta del queso luego de digitar nombre y la cantidad que deseo vender, el programa no me arroja nada y debería restármelo al inventario, pero tampoco. Agradezco su ayuda. No encuentro el error

```py
#Almacen de quesos
quesos=[["Nombre", "Cantidad","Precio"],["americano", 20,100],["mozarella",15,150],["costeño  ",30,80] ,["parmesano",10,200]]
quesos_mod=["",0,0,]

while True:
    mitupla=("\n-------Almacen de quesos--------------",
    "1. Productos",
    "2. Agregar Producto",
    "3. Vender Producto",
    "0. Salir")
    for i in range(len(mitupla)):
        print(mitupla[i])
    op=input("Digite su opción :")
    
    if op=="1":
        print("quesos")
        quesos.sort()
        for i in range(len(quesos)):
            for j in range(len(quesos[i])):
                print(f"{i+0}  {quesos[i][j]}  ", end="")
            print("")
           
        
         
        x=input("\n \n Presione ENTER para continuar")        
    
    elif op=="2":
        quesos_mod[0]=input(f"Digite el nombre del queso :")
        quesos_mod[1]=input(f"Digite La cantidad:")   
        quesos_mod[2]=input(f"Digite el precio:")   
        lista2=quesos_mod[:]
        quesos.append(lista2)
       
    
    elif op=="3":
        
        print("quesos")
        quesos.sort()
        for i in range(len(quesos)):
            for j in range(len(quesos[i])):
                print(f" {i+0} {quesos[i][j]}  ", end="")
            print("")
            
        queso=input("Digite el queso que desea vender")
        cantidad=int(input("Digite la cantidad que desea vender"))
        
        
        for i in range (len(quesos)):
            if queso==quesos[i][0]:
                if cantidad<=quesos[i][1]:
                    print(f"{quesos[i][0]}, cantidad {cantidad}, costo total {cantidad*quesos[i][2]}")
                    if seguro=="s":
                        quesos[i][1]=quesos[i][1]-cantidad
                    else:
                        print("Venta cancelada")
                        x=input("Presione ENTER para continuar")
                        
                else:
                    print(f"No hay la cantidad suficiente de {quesos[i][0]}, solo hay {quesos[i][1]}")
                    x=input("Presione ENTER para continuar")
                    
    else:
        print("Saliendo")
        break
```

Comment: por como describes tu problema, no tiene relación con el titulo.

Answer (score 1):

Solo me concentraré en la `opcion=="3"` y en algunas cosas del inicio, haces iteraciones innecesarias, por ejemplo al mostrar la variable `mitupla` donde no es necesario almacenar los valores en tuplas ni recorrerlos, podrías usar la sintaxis de *documentación* ósea las 3 comillas dobles (`""" texto """`), esto te permite mostrar textos con saltos de líneas.

```py
while True:
    #cambie el nombre de la variable a una mas acertada 
    menu=("""\n-------Almacen de quesos--------------
    "1. Productos"
    "2. Agregar Producto"
    "3. Vender Producto"
    "0. Salir""")
    print(menu)

    ....
```

Por otra parte al hacer `print(f"{i+0}  {quesos[i][j]}  ", end="")` estas mostrando el indice para cada vez que imprimes un dato. teniando algo como

```
0 Nombre 0 Cantidad 0 Precio
```

Puedes evitar esto simplemente imprimiendo la variable `i` en el primer bucle `for`

```py
    ...
    elif op=="3":
        print("quesos")
        quesos.sort()
        for i in range(len(quesos)):
            print(i,end="")
            for j in range(len(quesos[i])):
                print(f" {quesos[i][j]}  ", end="")
            print("")
```

Ahora si viene los interesante, tu código se puede reducir y se puede hacer *aprueba de errores*. Cuando pides la cantidad lo estas convirtiendo a entero, pero el usuario puede ingresar una letra y esto mostrará un error, puedes evitarlo poniéndolo en un `try/except` (por ahora yo no lo puse).

Luego vuelves a hacer un `for` parcialmente innecesario, pues recorres toda la lista de quesos en busca del queso pero no detienes el ciclo cuando lo encuentras. Reduje todo el ciclo `for` por una comprensión de lista, la cual devuelve la información del queso junto con su posición, esto hace mas fácil reemplazarlo. en caso no haya coincidencia lanza un error (esto por el `quesos.index()`), por tal razón se maneja con un `try/except`.

```py
        queso=input("Digite el queso que desea vender: ")
        cantidad=int(input("Digite la cantidad que desea vender: "))
        
        try:
            #obtenemos la informacion (lista de queso, posicion)
            data_queso = [(q,quesos.index(q)) for q in quesos[1:] if q[0] == queso][0]
        except:
             print("No se encontro el queso")

        pos = data_queso[1] #accedemos a la posicion
        new_queso = data_queso[0] #acedemos a la info del queso
        act_cantidad = new_queso[1] #accedemos a la cantidad

        if cantidad > act_cantidad: #verificamos la cantidad
            print("La cantidad a vender excede la actual")
        else:
            #actualizamos los valores
            new_queso[1]-=cantidad    
            quesos[pos] = new_queso 
            
        x=input("\n \n Presione ENTER para continuar")
```

Tu código se puede reducir mucho y se puede hacer mas legible, pero no haré eso, eso es tu trabajo :D.